# Asp Validations inside a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working on creating Modal pop-ups for CRUD operations.  I have created working modals for Create and Edit.  My issue is now I have no way to use the validations from the server side which I need to have.  When Edit fails the validation test it rightfully so rejects the request but redirects back to the Edit view in a non modal form. Please see below.

Modal:

[image]

After Invalid input:

[image]

I believe its going into the controller post edit and rendering from the URL.  Which its good as it gives the validation for the pin being empty correctly, However this would need to be rendered on the Modal Edit 1234 pop up.  Will include Model, controller , index view, Edit view, and js to help with the issue.  Thank you for your help.

Model:

```
    public class Airmen
{

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string MobileID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Pin { get; set; }


}
public class SuperModel
{
    public Airmen airmen { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Airmen> airmens { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(SuperModel arm)
{

    arm.airmens = await _context.Airmen.ToListAsync();
    return View(arm);
}
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
    {
        SuperModel airmen = new SuperModel();
        airmen.airmen = await _context.Airmen.FindAsync(id);
        return PartialView(airmen);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("MobileID,Pin")] Airmen airmen)
    {
        SuperModel amn = new SuperModel();
        
        if (id != airmen.MobileID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(airmen);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!AirmenExists(airmen.MobileID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        amn.airmen = airmen;
        return PartialView(amn);
    }
```

Index View:

```
    @model ALRSweb4.Models.SuperModel

@{ViewData["Title"] = "Index";}
<h1>Index</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Mobile ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Pin
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.airmens)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MobileID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pin)
                </td>

                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="#Edit" data-url="@Url.Action(item.MobileID,"Airmen/Edit")">
                        Edit
                    </button>
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.MobileID">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.MobileID">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CreateModal">
    Create
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="CreateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Create</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @Html.Partial("Create")
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="EditPlaceHolder">
</div>
```

Edit View:

```
@model ALRSweb4.Models.SuperModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<div class="modal fade" id="Edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit 12343</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <form asp-action="Edit">
                            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                            <input asp-for="airmen.MobileID" />
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="airmen.Pin" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="airmen.Pin" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="airmen.Pin" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />

                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

JS:

```
    // t2
$(function () {
    var CreatePlaceHolderElement = $('#EditPlaceHolder');
    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(url);
        $.get(decodedUrl).done(function (data) {
            CreatePlaceHolderElement.html(data);
            CreatePlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        })
    })

    CreatePlaceHolderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var sendData = form.serialize();
        $.post(actionUrl, sendData).done(function (data) {
            CreatePlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
            location.reload(true);
        })
    })

})
// end of t2
// start of function for create modal
$(function () {
    var CreatePlaceHolderElement = $('#CreatePlaceHolder');
    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function(event){
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(url).done(function (data) {
            CreatePlaceHolderElement.html(data);
            CreatePlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        })
    })

    CreatePlaceHolderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {
        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var sendData = form.serialize();
        $.post(actionUrl, sendData).done(function (data) {
            CreatePlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
            location.reload(true);
        })
    })

})
// end of function for create modal
```

Comment: You need to put the validations inside the modal. This way, if the user enters invalid input, the modal is not submitted. If the client side validation passes, then you can do server side validation on the server side.

Comment: There is no such element have `data-save="modal"`. There is a submit button in your edit view, it will form submit without ajax and get into your edit action and return partial view with model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.RenderPartialAsync` cannot render the js successfully by ajax call back. So the fastest way is to add the js in Edit view like below and it will prevent form submit:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

The ajax function below is useless, just **remove the following code** to use default form submit. The reason for why removing it is because firstly your code does not have any element with `data-save="modal"`. Then you have `<input type="submit" />` which will submit your form data by default without using ajax.

```
CreatePlaceHolderElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function (event) {
    var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
    var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
    var sendData = form.serialize();
    $.post(actionUrl, sendData).done(function (data) {
        CreatePlaceHolderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
        location.reload(true);
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this Rena.  Did not realize I had forgotten to add the client side validation scripts.  Question or I can post this on a separate question.  Once I run into the server side validation. I can redirect back to index and post an error message.  Will it be possible to open modal again and show this error in the correct edit modal from a list of edit buttons ?

Comment: Hi @tachidow, you use client side validation, so you will always get into the action unless the validation is passed. So your server side validation is always true.